# Babel on CodePen strange error

Tags: javascript, babeljs, codepen

I am using this line of code in my pen.

```
const CELLS = ([...Array(9).keys()]).map(key => '#cell' + key)
```

If just use this in console, it creates
 `["#cell0", "#cell1", "#cell2", "#cell3", "#cell4", "#cell5", "#cell6", "#cell7", "#cell8"]`, as expected.
But when I turn Babel on, I get this: `["#cell[object Array Iterator]"]`
But why?

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/TogusaRusso/pen/qjXGyM)